# How to optimize performance of an Angular 9 application and reactive forms

Tags: angular, performance, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular9

I am working on a large enterprise Angular SPA in an organization. The issue is, in the input fields of reactive forms, while typing the input the form-control fields get populated very slow like it takes 5-6 seconds to get populated on UI,
even on prod environment.

Regarding the Reactive forms used, there is usually one form-group for each page there are no nested form-group and there are not many form-controls in a form-group max 10-12. There are child components on a page but usually 1-2 components on a page.

I have separated out valuechanges on form-control so that only specific form-control value changes is called when the input value changes.
The team has given me the task to find a solution, 
I tried the following methods-

- used updateOn: 'blur'
- used debounce(400) and distinctUntilChanged() NgRx functions on input fields so that valueChanges is not called with every input.
- unsubscribed every subscribe in ngOnDestroy block.
- tried ChangedetectionStrategy to Onpush but the child components are not getting loaded so I didn't implement this technique.
- removed unnecessary imports on pages so the application doesn't get heavy.
- Separate valueChanges for single form-control.
- As less code as possible in ngOnint block.

The final solution I am currently trying is LazyLoading the components. 
And also I have seen somewhere that you have to write your form-groups in separate services or classes can improve performance.

Is there any other solution, or plugin, or something I am doing wrong or somebody else faced a similar situation and how did they overcome. Or is it the same with a large SPA in Angular?
Cant paste source code here for policy reason.

Comment: it's hard to help you without any example as 10-12 controls shouldn't even slow the update of your inputs. You should try to implement your form in an isolated project adding features one by one to see how it's going.

Comment: That shouldn't be slow, can you give more specifics in what exactly means 'it is slow', normally the control and the input are bound together so the 'population' should be as almost as fast as setting a property on an object. I guess what you say is that you display the value of the control somewhere and this could be an issue with change detection.

Comment: did you find any solution to this issue?